# Error ORA-06502 in BLOB retrieval

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, oracleforms

I'm trying to develop a procedure which will read a BLOB field of a table and write an RTF document which will be used as template to another procedure but when the procedure fires up the select statemente, i got stuck with a ORA-06502 error.

This error, after reading the documentation, is caused by incompatibilities between fields (numeric or value error string)

But i've seen this example everywhere in the internet and i'm running out of ideas of what is causing it.

The source code of my procedure follows:

```
PROCEDURE p_transfer_db_client(pcPath IN VARCHAR2,
                               pnSequence IN NUMBER) IS

   v_src_blob BLOB;
   v_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   v_offset INTEGER := 1;
   v_amount BINARY_INTEGER := 32766;
   v_binary_buffer RAW(32767);

BEGIN

   SELECT model 
     INTO v_src_blob
     FROM models
    wHERE id = pnSequence;

   v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(pcPath, 'model.rtf', 'wb', v_amount); 

   LOOP
      BEGIN
          DBMS_LOB.READ(v_src_blob, v_amount, v_offset, v_binary_buffer);
          UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW(v_file, v_binary_buffer);
          v_offset := v_offset + v_amount;
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
               EXIT;
      END;
   END LOOP;

   UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(v_file);
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);

END p_transfer_db_client;
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the table `models`? In particular, is your `id` column a VARCHAR2?

Comment: create table models
(
  inst_num_instituicao NUMBER(2) not null,
  id                   NUMBER(3) not null,
  model                BLOB not null
)

Comment: The `ORA-06502` means that you are trying to set a variable to value greater than its maximum value (e.g setting a VARCHAR2(2) to `XXX`). Which line exactly triggers the error?

Comment: The error is triggered exactly at the SELECT statement

Comment: number(2) isn't very long: is the pnSequence parameter to the procedure larger than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I hadn't seen that you had tagged this question as `forms`.

Your code won't work inside forms: UTL_FILE and DBMS_LOB run on the DB server, not the forms client so they should be in a PL/SQL procedure, not a Forms procedure.

I'm pretty sure the BLOB datatype is not managed like this in forms, in fact I'm surprised it even compiles!

Take a look at this [example showing how to handle blobs inside forms](http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-2615079.html) for instance, and you will see that you need to define and query the blob inside a PLSQL procedure, not directly through forms.

I suggest you create the procedure inside the DB as a PLSQL package and call this package from your forms client.

---

There is something else going on, I can't see why the SELECT statement wouldn't work.

Do you still get the error if you comment out all variables declarations and all the following statements, i.e:

```
SQL> create table models (
  2     inst_num_instituicao NUMBER(2) not null,
  3     id                   NUMBER(3) not null,
  4     model                BLOB not null);

Table created.

SQL> insert into models values (1, 1, hextoraw('FFFF'));

1 row created.

SQL> declare
  2     b blob;
  3  begin
  4     select model into b from models where id = 1;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: This procedure is being used inside an Oracle Forms 6i Form... in PL/SQL Developer i don't get any error

Comment: `UTL_FILE` and `DBMS_LOB` run on the DB server, not the forms client so they should be in a PL/SQL procedure, not a Forms procedure. I'm pretty sure the BLOB datatype is not managed like this in forms. Take a look at [this example](http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-2615079.html) for instance, and you will see that you need to define and query the blob inside a PLSQL procedure, not directly through forms.

Comment: I've reached another solution to this problem, modifying how i acquire the template file, doing now directly from the server file server. But thanks for all the help :)